# dynamically generated nested form with cocoon rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, cocoon-gem

I have a nested form with cocoon, but am having an issue trying to calculate my total price from the JavaScript. And when I check my view source page the generated attribute from the fields have no value attributes. If I use the `@invoice.line_items.build`,the total price is calculated but the dynamic fields fro the cocoon is not being seen. Thanks and awaiting any help I can get soon.

```
   class InvoicesController < ApplicationController

     before_action :set_invoice,:set_line_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

     def index
       @invoices = Invoice.all
     end

     def show
     end

     def new
       @invoice = Invoice.new
      @invoice.line_items.build
     end

     # GET /invoices/1/edit
     def edit

     end

     def create
       @invoice = Invoice.new(invoice_params)
       respond_to do |format|
        if @invoice.save
          format.html { redirect_to @invoice, notice: 'Invoice was successfully created.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @invoice }
        else
          format.html { render :new }
          format.json { render json: @invoice.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end

    def update
      respond_to do |format|
        if @invoice.update(invoice_params)
          format.html { redirect_to @invoice, notice: 'Invoice was successfully updated.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @invoice }
        else
          format.html { render :edit }
          format.json { render json: @invoice.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end

    def destroy
      @invoice.destroy
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to invoices_url, notice: 'Invoice was successfully destroyed.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      end
    end


    private

    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_invoice
      @invoice = Invoice.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_line_item
      @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.    
     def invoice_params
       params.require(:invoice).permit(:amount, :date, :currency, {line_items_attributes: 
        [:id,:quantity,:net_amount, :description, :unit_cost]})
     end

   end
```

---

```
 <tbody class='line_items'>
                <%= f.fields_for :line_items do |builder| %>
                <%= render 'line_item_fields', :f => builder %>
                <% end %> 
           </tbody>
      </table>
        <%= link_to_add_association 'add item', f, :line_items, class: "btn btn- 
  primary",data: {"association-insertion-node" => "tbody.line_items", "association-insertion-method" => "append"} %>
        <%= f.submit  class:"btn btn-primary" %>
```

---

```
  <tr class="nested-fields">
     <div class="container">
       <div class="row row-cols-5">
       <div class="col"> <td><%= f.text_field :description, class: "form-control item_desc" %></td></div><br/>
    <div class="col"> <td><%= f.text_field :quantity,  class: "form-control quantity" %></td></div><br/>
    <div class="col"> <td><%= f.text_field :unit_cost, class: "form-control unit_cost"%></td></div><br/>
    <div class="col"> <td class="price_td"><%= f.text_field  :net_amount, class: "form-control price", :readonly => true %></span> <span class= "subtotal_currency"></span></td></div><br/>
    <div class="col"> <td><%= link_to_remove_association 'Delete', f, class: 'remove_record btn btn-danger' %></td></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the javascript

```
  function update_price(){ 
      var row = $(this).parents('.nested-fields');
      var price = row.find('.unit_cost').val() * row.find('.quantity').val();
      price = price.toFixed(2);
      isNaN(price) ? row.find('.price').val('is not a number') : 
      row.find('.price').val(price);
      update_subtotal();

  }
```

Comment: When is the javascript function`update_price` called? Is it not working? Are you using cocoon callbacks  to  trigger it?  Can you show us how call it now?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Am not using the cocoon callbacks to trigger it. The update_price is called when I insert a value on the quantity and unit_cost field. The method returns the total price. But using the cocoon generated field, the update_method seems not to be functioning, And when I try viewing what was passed from the cocoon generated field its blank even via page source.

Comment: Can you show us how you link the `update_price` to the change event of the quantity and unit-cost fields?

Comment: I used the function below                                                                          
        function  bind(){
        $('.unit_cost').blur(update_price);
        $('.quantity').blur(update_price);
    }

Answer (score 0):

You attach the events using the following code:

```
$('.unit_cost').blur(update_price); 
$('.quantity').blur(update_price);
```

However, this will only bind the event-handlers to the elements on the page at the moment this command was run, and there is a better to achieve the same:

```
$(document).on('blur', '.unit_cost, .quantity', update_price)
```

I attach the event to top-level `document` (so this would even be turbolinks compatible, but you could also use the enclosing `form` or div), we respond to `blur` events but only if the triggering element has class `.unit_cost` or `.quantity`.

Comment: Thanks @nathanvda, I applied the change as stated and it worked. I still have an issue with after the insertion of the generated field values, it seems not saving inside the database. I only can save the field values of the "@invoice.line_items.build" method but not from the add_item field. What might be the likely problem with it. Thanks

Comment: A bit hard to tell, since you did not show the entire form, but some possible reasons: using html-ids instead of classes (repeating ids are not allowed and so it will only upload the first occurence of an id in a form), _or_ your  `link_to_add_association` adds the items outside of the form. I see you have a `</table>` before the `link` so this might force the closure of the form (if it was started inside the table). Otherwise, maybe you should ask another question and offer more details.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the detailed explanation given but what I meant was that the add_field button isn't generating a unique id for each line-item which made it impossible for it to be saved alongside the first line-item

Comment: Show me what is posted to the controller (check the logs). If the items are posted to the controller, they should be saved. I was saying they probably are not. Maybe it is clearer if you start a new question, because i am not sure i understand your new problem completely. Link it here so i can check it out.

Comment: OK, have just done that and the link is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59590890/cocoon-item-field-not-posting-values-to-database

Comment: Is there any reason why you would not accept this answer (actually, both my answers)?

Comment: They are actually correct, I didn't follow what you wrote carefully. Thanks for your time