# Cocoon Item field not posting values to database

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, cocoon-gem

I have a genearted lineItem field using Cocoon gem, am having issues trying to save the line items field values,and when I inspect the elements the add_item button wasn't triggering a unique ID for each new field generated.

```
  class InvoicesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_invoice,:set_line_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


def index
  @invoices = Invoice.all
end


def show

end

def new
   @invoice = Invoice.new
   @invoice.line_items.build
end


def edit

end


 def create
 @invoice = Invoice.new(invoice_params)

  respond_to do |format|
   if @invoice.save
    format.html { redirect_to @invoice, notice: 'Invoice was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @invoice }
   else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @invoice.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
   end
  end
 end


 def update
  respond_to do |format|
  if @invoice.update(invoice_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @invoice, notice: 'Invoice was 
    successfully updated.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @invoice }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @invoice.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
   end
 end
end

 def destroy
  @invoice.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to invoices_url, notice: 'Invoice was successfully destroyed.' }
  format.json { head :no_content }
  end
 end

private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
 def set_invoice
  @invoice = Invoice.find(params[:id])
 end

 def set_line_item
  @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])
 end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
#def invoice_params
  #params.require(:invoice).permit(:total_amount,  :issue_date, :currency, :description)
#end

def invoice_params
  params.require(:invoice).permit(:amount, :date, :currency, {line_items_attributes: [:id,:quantity,:net_amount, :description, :unit_cost]})
  end
 end
```

This is my form partial view
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTmni.png)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              <%= f.label :date %>
               <%= f.input_field :date , class: "form-control datepicker", as: :string, id: "invoice_date" %>
             </div>
            <div class="col">
                <%= f.label :currency %>
                 <%= f.input_field :currency , class: "form-control" , id: "invoice_currency" %>
            </div>

            <div class="col">
                <h5>Amount Due : <span class="bal" id="invoice_total">679.00</span><span class="subtotal_currency">
                </span></h5>
            </div>
       </div>
     </div>
 </div>

    <table class="table">
          <thead>
              <tr>
                <th class="description">Description</th>
                <th class="quantity">Quantity</th>
                <th class="cost">Unit Cost</th>
                <th class="price">Total Amount</th>
                <th class="action">Action</th>
              </tr>
           </thead>
            <tbody class='line_items'>
              <div id="task">
                  <%= f.simple_fields_for :line_items do |items| %>
                  <%= render 'line_item_fields', f: items %>
                <% end %>   
           </tbody>
    </table>
                  <div class='links'>
                    <%= link_to_add_association 'add item', f, :line_items, class: "btn btn-primary",data: {"association-insertion-node" => "tbody.line_items", "association-insertion-method" => "append"} %>
                    <%= f.submit  class:"btn btn-primary" %>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <br>
```

This is my nested form view

```
<tr class="nested-fields">
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row row-cols-5">
    <div class="col"> <td><%= f.text_field :description, class: "form-control item_desc" %></td></div><br/>
    <div class="col"> <td><%= f.text_field :quantity,  class: "form-control quantity" %></td></div><br/>
    <div class="col"> <td><%= f.text_field :unit_cost, class: "form-control unit_cost"%></td></div><br/>
    <div class="col"> <td class="price_td"><%= f.text_field  :net_amount, class: "form-control price", :readonly => true %></span> <span class= "subtotal_currency"></span></td></div><br/>
    <div class="col"> <td><%= link_to_remove_association 'Delete', f, class: 'remove_record btn btn-danger' %></td></div>
  </div>
</div>
</tr>
```

This is my javascript file

```
function update_price(){ 
    var row = $(this).parents('.nested-fields');
    var price = row.find('.unit_cost').val() * row.find('.quantity').val();
    price = price.toFixed(2);
    isNaN(price) ? row.find('.price').val('is not a number') : 
    row.find('.price').val(price);
    update_subtotal();    
}

$(document).on('cocoon:after-insert', '#task', function(added_task){
   // $('.links')
      //('cocoon:after-insert', function(e, added_task) {
       // console.log(added_task);
     // })
      $("#task").on('click', function(){
     console.log('looks like clicking works...'); //this works fine
   });

});

$(document).on('blur', '.unit_cost, .quantity', update_price)
```

These are the posted values to the controller

"authenticity_token"=>"qMr1sDqfOVTdjVvXzC3Hvejh3KXnoyburvHXwu7L6Qg1mSDqnagLo0gSXrUcpJumMeb1u9pPLz9OyaYndbeqBA==", "invoice"=>{"date"=>"2019/12/06","currency"=>"Naira", "line_items_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"description"=>"rice", "quantity"=>"2", "unit_cost"=>"56", "net_amount"=>"112.00", "_destroy"=>"false"}}}, "commit"=>"Create Invoice"}
 Unpermitted parameter: :_destroy

Comment: Can you show us what is posted to the controller? Check the logfile for the posted parameters. And please format your code correctly (fix the indentation).

Comment: Invoice Create   INSERT INTO "invoices" ("created_at", "updated_at", "currency") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", "2020-01-04 13:08:45.182484"], ["updated_at", "2020-01-04 13:08:45.182484"], ["currency", ""]]
  
  LineItem Create (1.2ms)  INSERT INTO "line_items" ("net_amount", "description", "quantity", "created_at", "updated_at", "unit_cost", "invoice_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["net_amount", 18.0], ["description", "rice"], ["quantity", 3.0], ["created_at", "2020-01-04 13:08:45.184837"], ["updated_at", "2020-01-04 13:08:45.184837"], ["unit_cost", 6.0], ["invoice_id", 48]]

Comment: Please show the parameters that are posted to the controller? On the line where the processing of the request is started, it should also show all the parameters (which is the contents of the form). This would explain if your html is correctly formed or not. Also please show the complete form-view code? Can you verify inside the html (inspect in the browser) that the inserted items using the `link_to_add_association` button are included in the form? (between the `<form></form>` tags?)

Comment: I have updated the information supplied earlier on so you can have a better understanding of my question, I have also added a screenshot of the page inspect performed on the add_item button. Thanks for your time

Comment: You can tell only one line_item is posted to the controller, so check your html. Weird: why are using a `<tr>` and then no `<td>` ?? Maybe you should not use a table at all? But, main reasons why this would happen: your inserted items are not _in_ the form (check the html, inspect the html), or you have repeating ids. What I already said in your other question.

Comment: Thanks so much for your support so far. You are right concerning the inserted items not in the form, that was the problem. Its fixed now and everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

From the parameters posted to the controller, we can see it is only 1 `line_item` and none of the dynamically added ones.

There are a few possible reasons for this:

- using html-ids for repeating elements. For instance the nested-items are inside a encapsulating element with a fixed html-id: since repeating id's are not allowed in html, but render correctly, they are ignored when collecting the form data. Only the first element would be saved.
- another common cause is that link-to-add-association inserts the nested element on the page, and everything "looks ok", but the nested items are *outside* the form thus never collected when posting the form. In this case only newly added items would never be saved.